# Getting Error 502 while routing to a containerized microservice though Ocelot gateway

Tags: docker-compose, ocelot, http-status-code-502

After deploying a .NET microservice and Ocelot gateway using docker-compose on the ubuntu server I got 502 gateway error. although it is working perfectly on the local machine.
below is the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  identity:
    image: hadaou/glb.identity:1.0.9
    container_name: glb.identity
    hostname: identity
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - RabbitMQSettings__Host=rabbitmq
      - MongoDbSettings__Host=mongo
      - SeqSettings__Host=seq
      - JaegerSettings__Host=jaeger
  gateway:
    image: hadaou/glb.gateway:1.0.18
    container_name: glb.gateway
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
```

and below is the Ocelot.json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/connect/token",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "identity",
          "Port": 5000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/identity-srv/connect/token",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": ["POST"]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "identity",
          "Port": 5000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/identity-srv/configuration",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": ["Get"]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{catchAll}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "identity",
          "Port": 5000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/identity-srv/{catchAll}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5173"
  }
}
```

I've created and published the service using the below command:

```
docker service create --name glb_gateway hadaou/glb.gateway:1.0.18
docker service update --publish-add published=80,target=5173 glb_gateway
```

Using postman if I post to http://193.188.136.135/api/v1/identity-srv I got the error 502 Bad Gateway

on the other hand if I post to http://localhost:5173/api/v1/identity-srv it is working fine with no error

tried to change "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5173" to "BaseUrl": "http://193.188.136.135:5173" it didn't work

Comment: The below warning appeared in the docker log of the glb.gateway container: